# Changing backgroundcolor on custom UITableViewCell won't show

Tags: uitableview, background-color

I'm trying to change the background color of a custom cell when clicked..  Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    if (...condition...) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
}
```

Now, I did debug, and the cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; gets executed, but the cell stays yellow!!!  This only happens to some of the cells (ones that are yellow, and reused)..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work.  Had to use 
   aCell.contentView.backgroundColor 
instead of 
   aCell.backgroundColor

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can persist the changes is to save it somewhere and use it while setting up the cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. So, maintain a set of cells which have a yellow background and while setting up a cell, check whether it is in the set. If yes, assign it a yellow background and if no, set it to clear color.

Answer (score 0):

Change the cell background color in custom cell class, where we have a method setbackground:.